# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

Boa tarde. Fiz um pequeno algoritmo no `Python`, apareceu o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

Alguém poderia me ajudar. Segue o código.

```
import numpy as np
import math
x=np.ones((3,1))
y=np.ones((3,1))
err=[]
for k in range(3,15):
    x=np.append(x,1.074*((x[k-1])**2)-2.042*x[k-2]*x[k-3])
    y=np.append(y,1.074*y[k-1]*y[k-1]-2.042*y[k-2]*y[k-3])
    err.append(math.fabs((x-y)/2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operações com arrays Numpy são vetoriais. Por exemplo: `np.array([1, 2, 3]) + np.array([4, 5, 6])` retorna `array([5, 7, 9])`.

Dessa forma, quando você faz `(x-y)/2` cria um novo array e, assim, a função `math.fabs` não pode operar já que ela espera um único valor (um escalar e não um vetor).

Você pode fazer assim:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.ones((3,1))
y=np.ones((3,1))

for k in range(3,15):
    x=np.append(x,1.074*((x[k-1])**2)-2.042*x[k-2]*x[k-3])
    y=np.append(y,1.074*y[k-1]*y[k-1]-2.042*y[k-2]*y[k-3])

err = np.abs((x-y)/2).tolist()
```